# What's wrong with my logic? (JS string Length)

Tags: javascript

A couple days ago, on a site that I'm the only author on, I added this code to a script:

```
if (PowerArray[0][0].length < 1);
{
    return false;
}
```

and everything worked fine. When PowerArray[0][0] was "70", the script ran. When PowerArray was empty, the script didn't run past the above quoted line.
This is no longer true. For the life of me, I can't figure it out. I tested with variants of the code, like below:

```
if (PowerArray[0][0].length < 1);
{
    alert(PowerArray[0][0].length);
    return false;
}
```

and set PowerArray[0][0] = "70". When I run the code, I get an alert with "2" in the text. This is the only place that I have an alert in the script. What's going on here, and how do I fix it?

Note: The expected behavior is, of course, no alert, because "70" has a length of 2, and shouldn't trigger the truth of the if.

Edit: 1) Yes, the `False` in the first block was a typo. It's been corrected. 2) The expected behavior was for it to stop processing if (and only if) PowerArray[0][0].length  was 0. 3) I had previously initialized PowerArray as an empty array, and then copied an array (which had the potential to be empty) into it.

Comment: You have some semicolons at the end of your `if` statements which might be causing issues.

Comment: I've not checked, but I'm fairly certain `False` shouldn't work at all. Typo?

Comment: Did you check your error console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove semicolon from if statement, it terminates your statement there.
And yes, when your PowerArray is empty, 
PowerArray[0][0] will throw an undefined error, 
So should put a null check for that as well.

Comment: it is a logical error, but not the reason for the later scripts not running when `PowerArray ` is empty

Comment: @ArunPJohny but it is why the asker is observing 70 in his array. Upvoting your answer, however, because that's the next issue OP will encounter.

Answer (score 3):

when `PowerArray` is empty `PowerArray[0]` gives undefined then you will get an error for `PowerArray[0][0]` saying `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` that is why the script is nor running after that line

```
if (PowerArray && PowerArray[0] && PowerArray[0][0] && PowerArray[0][0].length < 1)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Still has a syntax error, because `False` is not a valid Javascript keyword. Unless I'm missing something... And you missed the trailing semicolon...

Comment: @tjameson missed it totally

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   if (PowerArray[0]) {
            if (PowerArray[0][0].length < 1) {
                return False;
            }
        }
```

Comment: apart from the extra semicolon you didn't fix... if the value is falsy, its length (if it has any) would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think the semicolon after the if is the issue. 
I would also check if PowerArray is a valid 2D array implementation.
Check this link for ideas [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Start by changing it to this `if (PowerArray[0][0].length < 1)`